# how to make bash not to wrap output?

Tags: command-line, bash

Whenever some command generates long lines as output ( for example, when `ls -l` a folder which contains files with long names ), the long lines are wrapped to next line, thus messing up the column structure.

Is there any way of avoiding this ? Something akin to the 'nowrap' vim option ?

---

**update**

I noticed an issue with the accepted answer:
if I make an alias like: `alias ll="tput rmam; ls -l; tput smam"`
and then try to  grep it's output: `ll | grep foo`
it will still print *all* files, like without the grep.

The solution I found is to put brackets around the whole alias:
`alias ll="(tput rmam; ls -l; tput smam)"`

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/how-to-disable-line-wrap-in-a-terminal

Comment: related https://superuser.com/q/600677/105108

Comment: Small note: if you use curly braces `{ ... }` instead of parenthesis `( ... )`, your command won't be needlessly run in a subshell.  Make sure to add a semicolon at the very end, to make it work properly: `alias ll="{ tput rmam; ls -l; tput smam; }"`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Note that this has nothing to do with bash (once you've launched the command, bash just waits for it to finish) and everything to do with the terminal.

Most terminal emulators wrap at the right margin by default. But this can be turned off by using the appropriate [control sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms), if the terminal emulator supports it; then long lines are simply truncated:

```
printf '\033[?7l'
ls -l /a/folder/that/contains/files/with/long/names
printf '\033[?7h'
```

Comment: yep, this is what I was looking for, thanks Gilles !

Comment: More portably: `tput rmam; ls -l longname; tput smam`

Comment: even better; but where did [rs]mam come from ? I searched tput and termcap manuals but couldn't find anything about them ?

Comment: @Mihai: try the terminfo documentation (`man 5 terminfo` on Linux).

Comment: indeed, it's there

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Put that command in an answer and I'll vote it up

Answer (score 25):

If you'd like to be able to do horizontal scrolling instead of truncating the lines, use [`less -S`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/).

Answer (score 6):

You could use a function like so:

```
nowrap() 
{ 
   cut -c-$(tput cols); 
}
```

keep in mind though you will have to prefix commands with `nowrap` or whatever you name the function.

Comment: it works, but I lose color coding; any way of preserving that as well ?

Comment: @MihaiRotaru Many cli tools that support color disable color when they are outputting to another application. Some such tools have a flag such as `--color=always` which disables this color suppression.

Answer (score 5):

You can [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25399516/1483861) a function so that it automatically runs `tput rmam` before your grep and `tput smam` after:

```
function grep () {
  tput rmam;
  command grep "$@";
  tput smam;
}
```

Drop that in your `.bash_profile` and whenever you run `grep`, it'll grep without line wrapping.

*This has been heavily edited, apologies to the commentators.*

Comment: The `sleep 20` is amazing :-)

Answer (score 5):

pipe it to less command with -S switch:

```
ls -l | less -S
```

Then you can use arrows up/down/left/right to scroll and type q to quit.

Comment: This is clean, simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function nowrap { export COLS=`tput cols` ; cut -c-$COLS ; unset COLS ; echo -ne "\e[0m" ; }
```

Comment: sorry for the gold shovel