# bash disable line wrap without truncation

Tags: bash

I am using a template heavy library in C++ and need to understand the template errors. Reading line wrapped template errors is a serious pain.

Is there a way to disable line wrapping in bash without also truncating the output. Additionally, is there a way to do horizontal scrolling on the output.

I have seen this answer, [how to make bash not to wrap output?](https://superuser.com/questions/188865/how-to-make-bash-not-to-wrap-output), but the output is truncated.

The solution doesn't have to be bash targeted, if there is method for this using another shell, tmux, piping make output to another program, compiling from within vim, etc. I'll use it (except for copy-pasting into gedit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More related to your main question (i.e. debugging your template-heavy library), you could use [gccfilter](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/gccfilter.html) for easier reading. In particular `-r`.

You can of course read the compilation output from a text editor, where the wrapping will be according to your editor:

`make >& comp_output && vi comp_output`

Comment: A Bash shortcut: `vi <(make 2>&1)`.

Comment: @DanielAndersson: Good point! Although on some systems I've come across complaints that the input is not from a terminal. But I don't remember the specifics of these systems.