# more is wrapping the lines

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I found the below function online (thanks to whoever wrote it}. The problem seems to be more is wrapping the output. I like the option to view output page by page but do not like wrapping. How can I change to no line wrapping but allow for scrolling the output like less or more commands?

```
#  Find a pattern in a set of files and highlight them:
#+ (needs a recent version of egrep).
function fstr()
{
    OPTIND=1
    local mycase=""
    local usage="fstr: find string in files.
Usage: fstr [-i] \"pattern\" [\"filename pattern\"] "
    while getopts :it opt
    do
        case "$opt" in
           i) mycase="-i " ;;
           *) echo "$usage"; return ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "$usage"
        return;
    fi
    find . -type f -name "${2:-*}" -print0 | \
xargs -0 egrep --color=always -sn ${case} "$1" 2>&- | more

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setterm -linewrap off`?

Comment: [`less -S`](https://superuser.com/a/188933/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That option creates a lot of [ESC] in the output. It becomes unreadable.

Comment: @DavidPostill works when I set that up in bashrc but is there a local way that is restricted to the function that I can use. I don't want to set a global off.

Comment: [`less -r`](https://superuser.com/a/117842/432690) then.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski works great with `less -r`

Answer (score 0):

```
function fstr()
{
    OPTIND=1
    local case=""
    local usage="fstr: find string in files.
Usage: fstr [-i] \"pattern\" [\"filename pattern\"] "
    while getopts :it opt
    do
        case "$opt" in
        i) case="-i " ;;
        *) echo "$usage"; return;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "$usage"
        return;
    fi
    find . -type f -name "${2:-*}" -print0 | \
    xargs -0 egrep --color=always -sn ${case} "$1" 2>&- | less -r

}
```